# A palavra "besnico" tem feminino?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

Um besnico é um miúdo:

> [1] [Informal]  Criança pequena. = MIÚDO

- A palavra "besnico" pode ser usada no feminino?

Não encontro indicações nesse sentido em dicionário nenhum...

As palavras semelhantes "garoto" e "miúdo" *podem* ser usadas no feminino: "garota" e "miúda".
E quanto a "**besnico**"?

---

[1]:
"besnico", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, http://priberam.pt/dlpo/besnico [consultado em 21-11-2016].

Comment: Única coisa que encontrei sobre isso: https://books.google.com.br/books?id=UzOtOLiBomYC&pg=PT47&lpg=PT47&dq=uma+besnico&source=bl&ots=L6pDWLZPZe&sig=BiwIzG81pVUvIzfZxpAlOkbjTwQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiepLKT5bjQAhWCFZAKHTraB-8Q6AEIMTAE#v=onepage&q=uma%20besnico&f=false

Comment: miúdo, besnico, puto, putinho, nada disso é usado por aqui. (RJ, Brasil)  Os miúdos que conheço são de galinha.  E não são os filhotes.

Comment: em pt-BR miúdos = órgãos internos de animais quando usados na culinária; besnico = nunca ouvi; puto = fulano ou palavrão; putinho = palavrão

Comment: @AndréLyra Sim, em pt-PT também temos miúdos de galinha, os órgãos internos. E puto (=criança) excecionalmente não tem feminino, por causa de "puta" ter uma carga negativa muito grande (prostituta) - e por isso não incluí esta palavra nos exemplos da pergunta.

Comment: Para o sul do Brasil valem os mesmos comentários do @Centaurus.

Comment: Nada te impede de dizer *besnica*, mas acho que também nunca ouvi. Mesmo *besnico* é raro, pelo menos aqui em baixo. Mas repara que os dicionários não indicam quando é que o nome tem versão feminina. Se vires *garoto*, também só te dizem que é nome masculino, mas toda a gente sabe que existe *garota* também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já se encontra ***besnica*** na net. Mas a palavra é rara e provavelmente recente. Por isso não a econtras nos dicionários: os dicionários só registam uma palavra depois do pessoal começar a usá-la. Mas para teres a certeza que uma forma feminina não está num dicionário online, tens de a procurar diretamente. Por exemplo em [*garoto* (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/garoto) também não se diz nada acerca da forma feminina; mas encontra-la se procurares diretamente [*garota* (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/garota). Mas de facto se procurares [*besnica*, o Priberam](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/besnica) responde com «palavra não encontrada».

Eu sempre achei que ***besnico*** enquanto ‘criança’ era usado figuradamente. Até porque também se ouve chamar às crianças pequenas ***besnico de gente***. Nunca me preocupei em saber qual seria o sentido primário de *besnico*, e os dicionários dizem apenas que significa ‘garoto’ e ‘criança’. Mas encontrei esta [*Revista de Portugal* de 1966](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Y9s_AQAAIAAJ&q=besnico&dq=besnico&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlttufzr7QAhVCvxQKHd7QDF4Q6AEIJTAB) que diz que significa ‘pedacinho’:

> BESNICO—Pedacinho. «Tirou um besnico para o prato», serviu-se de pouca porção de comida.

Então *besnico* parece ser originalmente um substantivo masculino, sem versão feminina, e é por isso que nós ouvimos sobretudo *besnico* mesmo quando falando de meninas. Agora nada nos impede de inovar e dizer *besnica*. Foi o que sucedeu com *pimpolho* e *pimpolha*. Originalmente [*pimpolho* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/pimpolho) era apenas um broto de videira. Depois começou a chamar-se *pimpolho* às crianças; e naturalmente o pessoal criou a versão feminina *pimpolha*, que agora é muito comum.

E na verdade, embora pouco comum, já se encontra *besnica*. Por exemplo, neste [*blogue da espiga* (2009)](http://bloguedaespiga.blogspot.pt/2009/04/o-meu-besnico-de-gente.html) encontramos (ênfase minha):

> **O meu besnico de gente** surpreendeu-me este fim-de-semana com novas palavras: có-ân (collant), bigo (umbigo), meia e mó-a (mola). Esta última tem uma história engraçada. Imagino o que se terá passado na cabeça **da besnica** enquanto conversava ontem ao colo da sua mãe, as duas à janela, com a roupa a secar na corda.

Comment: Jacinto mas há que ter cuidado, garota no Brasil pode ser outra coisa... Assim como "o puto" só pode ser usado no masculino. Quanto a besnico não sei, nem sequer conheço a palavra.

Comment: @JorgeB. Isso é como tudo. Em Portugal, *meninas* também pode ser outra coisa. Eu já tinha ouvido *besnico* e *besnico de gente*, que, descobri agora, vem a ser *pedacinho de gente*.

Comment: Jacinto será que "nico de gente" ou "arranja-me um niquinho" vem de besnico?

Comment: @JorgeB. Olha, *nico de gente* não conhecia eu! Nem *nico* sequer; só *niquinho*; é possível que tenham origem comum, sim.